# Is it possible to store a LINQ command as a string and then execute at runtime?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using MVC3, Razor, C# and EF4.1.

I am trying to implement some rule processing logic, and using the excellent FLEE rule processor at present. So rules such as :

```
a>1 and a<100
```

can be stored in the DB and processed at runtime. Great. However this assumes that I can preload "a" which in simple case I can. However sometimes it is necessary to get more detailed with my query and a dynamic type of LINQ would be great, ie

```
context.animals.first(r=>r.specie=="dog").Name
```

So one could then use this in the complete rule like:

```
(context.animals.first(r=>r.specie=="dog").Name) = "Rover"
```

It is "=" in FLEE and not "==" btw.

So can one implement dynamic LINQ queries and how?

The only other approach I can think of is substitution and use of switch ie:

```
{DogName}="Rover"

switch (argname)
{
case "DogName" :
  myValue = db.Animals.First(r=>r.specie=="Dog").Name
  break;
}
```

Comment: [Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: [Serialize.Linq - C# library to serialize LINQ expressions](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq)

Comment: Ok, thanks folks, some excellent feedback, need to check these out.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this.  Dynamic Linq is one.  Albahari's Predicate Builder is another.